# In Flutter, how to make a widget pop up when a TextButton is pressed?

Tags: flutter, menu, popup

How to implement the App described next? The App is composed of a Container containing at least a TextButton widget. When the TextButton is tapped (onPressed), a widget W should pop up just below the Textbutton. A tap outside W makes W disappear (there may be other clickable widgets outside W and the TextButton). W itself may be composed of widgets, say a TextButton T, a PopupMenuButton, a small green container, and an icon. A tap in one of these widgets, say the green container, makes widget X pops up. A tap into another widget such as the icon makes another widget Y pops up. Again, a tap outside W and X makes both disappear.

Comment: You should add your efforts here first!

Answer (score 1):

In TextButton onPressed, return with a function of showDialog where you can create a alertDialog.
Inside this alertDialog, we can return whatever widget we want in popup.

```
TextButton(
        child: Text("d"),
        onPressed: () => showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context){
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Text("Whatever Widget"),
          );
        })
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click `TextButton`, You can show other widget in `AlertDialog`, i am sharing an example of circular progress.

```
  TextButton( onPressed: () {
                      showLoaderDialog(context);
                    },
                    child: Text("press Text Button")),
```

`showLoaderDialog(context);`  is a function. you may put any widget `content`.

```
 showLoaderDialog(BuildContext context) {
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      content: Row(
        children: [
          CircularProgressIndicator(),
          Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 7), child: Text("Please wait...")),
        ],
      ),
    );
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Is there a way of showing the AlertDialog (or other widget) some 20 pixels below the TextButton?

Comment: if you just want to display simple text, you can use drop down button, if you want to use widget you may use Stack Widget.
step1.
Text Button and Custom Widget in Stack
Step 2
use any state management way, where you will hide and show Custom Widget using state management method.

Answer (score 1):

```
const TextButton({
    Key key,
    @required VoidCallback onPressed,
    VoidCallback onLongPress,
    ButtonStyle style,
    FocusNode focusNode,
    bool autofocus = false,
    Clip clipBehavior = Clip.none,
    @required Widget child,
  })
```

1. 

```
TextButton(
    child: Text('Click me'),
    onPressed: () {
      print('Pressed');
    }
  )
```

2. 

```
TextButton.icon(
    label: Text('click me'),
    icon: Icon(Icons.web),
    onPressed: () {
      print('Pressed');
    }
  )
```